# Exclude Pinterest pins of the same image from the same domain

Tags: search, pinterest

Where can you set up a search filter in Pinterest to not have to see the same image or photo that's been pinned and sourced from the same domain?

In this example, we've got a hankering for some potatoes and among the many shots of hash are things like the two here:

[image: potatoes on pinterest]

They're both from the same website, PlainChicken.com, but the doubling up is getting in the way of seeing more distinct or different potato pins because of this duplication.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to actually have the filter be by link url than the actual image?

Comment: A lot of times an image does not get pinned from the same URL @car

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this at the moment. On first guess for a possible solution, would be some user script that pops off subsequent duplicates from the display or an entirely different app altogether to handle search filters when Pinterest decides to open up again http://pinterest.com/developers/api/ (404).