# Obtain Pinterest image's source URL

Tags: images, pinterest

Pinterest lets users post images from other websites as a sort of image bookmark. Often when I come across a Pinterest post, I am interested in the original full-resolution source.

Pinterest posts have a "Website" link pointing to the web page the user pinned the image from. For [this picture of a puppy](http://www.pinterest.com/pin/194288171396825405/), this links back to the gallery page for that specific image on Imgur (`http://imgur.com/gallery/PSP7XRR`), which is good.

However, frequently Pinterest posts just link uselessly to a website's home page or other time-dependent pages (commonly Tumblr blogs), which doesn't help much for finding the original image. For instance, [this puppy picture](http://www.pinterest.com/pin/183451384790861972/) goes to the source website's home page (`http://www.cutestpaw.com/`).

Can you get the source URL of the image itself from Pinterest?

(I'm aware of external reverse-image-search tools like Google Images and TinEye; these can't always find the source of an image. I'm asking whether Pinterest lets you see where it got the image from.)

*Somewhat related (also involving image source URLs): [Exclude Pinterest pins of the same image from the same domain](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/23953/exclude-pinterest-pins-of-the-same-image-from-the-same-domain)*

Comment: It seems cannot get the **original image** url you want, instead, you can get the url of the exact image from pinterest cache server as this(in your case):https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/95/8f/49/958f49b4ff4a48df534fd2b5020156ba.jpg By right clicking on the image, and select open image in another tab(chrome, and browser only currently.)

Answer (score 2):

> Can you get the source URL of the image itself from Pinterest?

Not necessarily - because there might not even be one.

Pinterest doesn't require the pinned image to be on the web-page.   I can upload an image from my computer, and then after it was pinned to a board I could edit the pin, and attach an URL to it.    There is no connection between the image and the URL.
(Worked example:  http://www.pinterest.com/pin/158259374379943925/  )

Answer (score 0):

https://www.pinterest.com/pin/844002786391771933/

With this link, use the Chrome browser as example.

right - click on the picture, then click 'copy image address',get the picture address.

https://i.pinimg.com/564x/27/5c/fc/275cfc51e60c6e3ef11101b3890bafa8.jpg

Change '/564x/' to '/originals/' then get the full size picture url address

https://i.pinimg.com/originals/27/5c/fc/275cfc51e60c6e3ef11101b3890bafa8.jpg